# custom UITableViewCell conent misplaced

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

Hello friends I am using custom UITableViewCell in my app and cell contains two label. When user taps on cell the new cell gets added at the bottom of cell to display new functionality, but problem comes in picture when user once again click on cell to destroy the expanded cell and then location of label gets changed.

So now I'm not getting how these label's get misplaced....

`-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:   (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
        [self cellExpandCollapsewithIndex:(int)indexPath.row];
    }

 - (void) cellExpandCollapsewithIndex :(int)IndexPathRow
    {
        NSDictionary *dic=[self.itemsInTable objectAtIndex:IndexPathRow];
        if([dic valueForKey:@"SubItems"])
        { NSArray *arr=[dic valueForKey:@"SubItems"];
            BOOL isTableExpanded=NO;
            for(NSDictionary *subitems in arr )
            { NSInteger index=[self.itemsInTable  indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:subitems];
                isTableExpanded=(index>0 && index!=NSIntegerMax);
                if(isTableExpanded) break;
            }
            if(isTableExpanded)
            {
                [self CollapseRows:arr];
            }
            else
            {
                NSUInteger count=IndexPathRow+1;
                NSMutableArray *arrCells=[NSMutableArray array];
                for(NSDictionary *dInner in arr )
                {
                    [arrCells addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:count inSection:0]];
                    [self.itemsInTable insertObject:dInner atIndex:count++];
                }
                [self.menuTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:arrCells  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: Posting your code could help us solve the problem. Right now all we can tell you is that something is wrong (which you already know), since that's basically all the information we have.

Comment: `-(void)CollapseRows:(NSArray*)ar
    {
        for(NSDictionary *dInner in ar )
        {
            NSArray *arInner=[dInner valueForKey:@"SubItems"];
            if(arInner && [arInner count]>0)
            {
                [self CollapseRows:arInner];
            }
            if([self.itemsInTable indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:dInner]!=NSNotFound)
            {
                [self.itemsInTable removeObjectIdenticalTo:dInner];
                [self.menuTableView reloadData];
            }
        }
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be load of things:

-have you set prepareForReuse() and init(style:reuseIdentifier:) functions in your CustomCell class?

-are you using default labels for cell style? Make sure you are not overwriting default UITableViewCell labels: i.e. titleLable, textLabel, imageView etc...

Maybe better post your code so people can try to figure out what could be wrong.

Comment: No I'm using my own labels named lblTitle and textLabel

Comment: Are you using constrains to place labels? Try forcing constrains or position in init. Change also textLabel var name.

Comment: thanx man... the problem gets solved.That's all because I'm using default name to my label i.e.textLabel

Comment: Glad to know! I will edit answer to fit better with solution :)